# Right to left text scroller

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm planning on running a script that uses PHP's "file_get_contents" function to pull stock price data from a website, which is then manipulated with jQuery and fed to a 3rd party website as an iFrame.

So far its successfully importing the data, however the iFrame is too narrow for everything to be displayed. Anyone know of a simple jQuery text scroller, that loops the contents of a div from right to left?

Code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ticker</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.yfi_quote_summary_page{display:none;}
.time_rtq_ticker{font-weight:bolder;}
.down_r{color: #c00;font-weight:bold;}
.up_r{color: #080;font-weight:bold;}
.yfi_rt_quote_summary_rt_top .time_rtq{display:none;}
#time, #currentPrice{float:left;display:inline;font-size:16px;}
#currentPrice p{margin:0;}
#time{margin-right:16px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=STT.L');
if( $content !== FALSE ) {
  echo $content;
}
?>
<script>
$(function(){
   /*Copy HTML element*/
   var $importedData = $(".yfi_rt_quote_summary_rt_top").clone(true);
   var $time = $(".time_rtq").clone(true);
   $('body').empty();
   $('body').append('<div id="ticker"><div id="time">Stock price at </div><div id="currentPrice"></div></div>');
   $('#currentPrice').append($importedData);
   $('#time').append($time);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try adding overflow css to iframe.`overflow: auto;`

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the user to have to interact with the iFrame to see its content. I just want the content (e.g. the imported data) to slowly scroll horizontally.

Comment: Have you checked this post?

[jQuery scroll text side-to-side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408641/jquery-scroll-text-side-to-side)

Comment: Ah brilliant, I'll give one of the examples a go: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this website which helped me achieve what I was looking for: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html