# stop and play marqee text animation

Tags: jquery, animation

```
<div id="mqtext">text text text</div>
```

css

```
#mqtext{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:3px;
   overflow:hidden;
   white-space:nowrap;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

js

```
$('#mqtext').bind('marquee', function() {
  var ob = $(this);
  var tw = ob.width();
  var ww = ob.parent().width();
  ob.css({ right: -tw });
  ob.animate({ right: ww }, 70000, 'linear', function() {
  ob.trigger('marquee');
  });
  }).trigger('marquee');
```

This is a simple marquee text, and it works, but I'm trying to stop it with mouseover.

```
$('#mqtext').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop();
});
```

This also works, the text is stopped, but it doesn't play again when cursor is away.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408641/jquery-scroll-text-side-to-side#answer-18647696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is all you need:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iXOrAcE/5/edit)**

```
var ob = $('#mqtext'),
    w = ob.width();
ob.css({right:-w});

function marqee(){
    if(ob.position().left+w<0) ob.css({right:-w});
    ob.animate({right:'+=4'}, 60, 'linear', marqee);
}
marqee(); // Start

ob.hover(function( e ) {
    return e.type=='mouseenter' ? $(this).stop() : marqee();
});
```

Comment: Roko, there is no scroll repetition in your example. Also, after each stop scrolling is much slower !

Comment: @SunSky  sorry, **Fixed**

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that you can't get the text to start moving again when the mouse leaves, the code below will fix that.

[NEWEST UPDATED Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJb9E/8/)

I just went ahead and reworked the code for you so that it fixes the slow problem and it's also much easier to read:

```
var ob = $("#mqtext"),
    tw = ob.width(),
    ww = ob.parent().width() + tw;

function slideAnimate() {
    ob.animate({       
        right: '+=' + ww
    }, 7000, 'linear');
    ob.animate({
        right: '-=' + ww
    }, 1, slideAnimate);
}

ob.css({ right: -tw });
$(slideAnimate);

ob.mouseenter(function() {
    ob.stop(true, false);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    slideAnimate();
});
```

Comment: rogMaHall, after each mouseleave the scrolling is much slower !

Comment: Right you are @SunSky, thank you for pointing that out :) I've updated the fiddle and my answer above to reflect an even easier layout for the same situation.

Comment: In your edited example: http://jsfiddle.net/sJb9E/3/ on first iteration or Once you hover the element it  goes buggy.

Comment: `.stop(true, false)` ? why that? `2 quewed animations` why?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It wasn't bugging out for me at first, but I noticed after you mentioned that so it should work now. The second argument isn't really necessary, I just forgot that it defaulted to false. Setting stop to true is necessary to stop the currently running animation though.

Comment: @rogMaHall take a look after you open the fiddle. The marquee just **disappears** for some time... http://jsfiddle.net/sJb9E/6/ and also starts from the **wrong right position**

Comment: also a `;` after `function(){}` is wrong code, CSS `overflow:hidden;` on a marqee text is unnecessary. What is `$(slideAnimate);` a jQuery object or a `function` call?

Comment: @rogMaHall After your edit: Hover your element and it goes crazy again

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just forgot to transfer over the `ob.css({ right: -tw });` when I reworked the code and got some of the math screwed up in the process. The `;` was a type :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Whoaaa ok, hold on a minute.

Comment: @rogMaHall What you want to achieve is: http://jsbin.com/iXOrAcE/7/edit **but that's exactly my answer** `:-)` (here I removed just the ternary operators and made it longer) :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I like your answer and it's definitely correct, but now I just want to try another solution with the hope of adding some value to this answer thread rather than just deleting what I have :)

Comment: @rogMaHall Can't wait to see! In the meanwhile I even shortened my code: http://jsbin.com/iXOrAcE/9/edit